# can $f$ twice differentiable on $(0, 1)$ and continous on $[0,1]$ have a derivative discontinuous on $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

As I wrote in the title can the first derivative of $f$ be discontinous on $[0,1]$ given
$f(x): [0,1] \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ twice differentiable on $(0,1)$ and continuous on $[0,1]$?

My idea is to use a function like:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle x\sin\frac1x & \text{if } x \neq 0, \\
0 & \text{if } x = 0.\end{cases}$$
Which is continuous, differentiable on $(0,1)$ and it does not have a derivative in $0$ (which I understand means tha the derivative is discontinuous).
I am not sure if it is twice differentiable though.

Comment: what about taking the above function f(x) and integrating from 0 to x to obtain g(x). then g(x) will satisfy above conditions and then its second derivative will not be continuous

Comment: the question is about the discontinuity of the first derivative not the second

Comment: sorry I misunderstood the question

Comment: i think that the function f(x) is twice differentiable on (0,1) the only problem point seems to be 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your $f$, $f' = sin(1/x) - (1/x)cos(1/x)$, which is a composition of differentiable functions on $(0,1)$, so yes this function satisfies all your conditions.

Comment: that's what I wanted to know